# Mount OSX drive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, hfs+

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a second partition of a iMac 21.5''.
Now, I need to access to OSX partition but I cannot load it into Ubuntu...
I have hfsprogs, hfsutils and hfsplus installed inside ubuntu and tried to mount:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda2 /mnt/osx
```

and the result is:

```
root@pc:~# mount -t hfsplus /dev/sda2 /mnt/osx/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Next I tried to validate if the partition is correct and `fdisk` returns strange information:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *      409640   947643135   473616748   da  Non-FS data
/dev/sda3       947643136   948912671      634768   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda4       948914176   964538367     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

OSX partition (HFS+) has `/dev/sda2` but fdisk does not recognizes as this type of partition...
Anyone can help me to identify the problem?

---

Here is gdisk output:

```
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 951953B8-7795-4968-A50C-A092E96842ED
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2933 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       947643135   451.7 GiB   AF05  Untitled
   3       947643136       948912671   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   4       948914176       964538367   7.5 GiB     8200  
   5       964538368      1953523711   471.6 GiB   8300
```

Comment: fdisk does not work on GPT drives. Use gdisk instead. Why do you think your OSX partition is /dev/sda2? The output shows /dev/sda3 is the HFS partition.

Comment: Thanks. I know that is /dev/sda2 by the size of the partition, that is precisely the size reported by OSX. /dev/sda3 is a small partition.

Comment: Can you add the output of gdisk to the question? Perhaps your GPT and MBR records have become out of sync, in which case look into [gptsync](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182686/gptsync-mismatch-problem)

Comment: Also see [gptsync: GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found, will not touch this disk](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1297229)

Comment: gdisk tells that this partition if of type "af05 Apple Core Storage"...

Comment: It seems this question is a duplicate of [How to mount Apple Core Storage partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272351/how-to-mount-apple-core-storage-partition). Check the answer there (Linux does not support CoreStorage natively but it may be possible to do it with a FUSE library).